# Pausing audio when clicking on another audio element

Tags: javascript, audio, playback

I am attempting to get back into the projects I was building about 4 months ago. I stopped coding for that amount of time and boy am I struggling. Basically, my app plays a song with an image is clicked. Problem is, if you click on a different image, the 1st audio continues to play. What am I missing here?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <script src="Resources\js\p5.js"></script>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="Resources\js\p5.dom.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Resources\css\style.css">
  <title>Pressn.Listen</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Pressn.Listen</h1>

    <section>
    <ul id="image-list" style="list-style-type: none">
      <li><input type="image" class="images" src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/v4mfc9ql89q60hn/DSCF8693.jpg?dl=0" alt="pink-flowers"></input></li>
      <li><input type="image" class="images" src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/ywri0sg4i16nbc2/DSCF7307.jpg?dl=0" alt="overpass-sky"></input></li>
      <li><input type="image" class="images" src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/xpslama3reuniwz/DSCF6953.jpg?dl=0" alt="home-doorway"></input></li>
      <li><input type="image" class="images" src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/73xltoeeoyq78y7/20181029-DSCF6165.jpg?dl=0" alt="garage"></input></li>
    </ul>
    </section>
    <footer>
      <nav>
        <ul id="nav-bar" style="list-style-type: none">
          <li>
            <a class="links" target="_blank" href="https://mobile.twitter.com/eddiepearson">Twitter</a>
          </li>
             <li>
            <a class="links" target="_blank" href="https://github.com/eddiepearson">Github</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
     </footer>

     <audio id="song1" src="Resources\sounds\loopy loop 1.mp3"></audio>
     <audio id="song2" src="Resources\sounds\Automation city master.mp3"></audio>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Resources\js\app.js"></script>
</html>

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Mono');

* { 
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Roboto Mono', monospace;
}

body, html {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

body {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

header {
  text-align: right;
  margin: 3rem;
}

h1 {
  margin: 5rem 0 1rem 7rem;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(0,25,36,1) 0%, rgb(118, 181, 211) 0%, rgba(255,206,249,1) 36%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
   background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

#image-list {
  margin: 8rem auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 10px;
  max-width: 1000px;
}

.images {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 0 0 rgba(19, 19, 19, 0.15);

}

.ease {
  /* transition: transform 2.5s ease-out;
  transform: translateY(4px);
  transform: scale(2);  */
  animation-name: stretch;
  animation-duration: 2.5s; 
  animation-timing-function: ease-out; 
  animation-delay: 0;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-fill-mode: none;
  animation-play-state: running;
}

@keyframes stretch {
  0% {
    transform: scale(.3);
  }
  50% {
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1.5);
  }
}

input:hover {
  -webkit-filter: brightness(70%);
  filter: brightness(70%);
  transition: 0 3s ease;
}

#nav-bar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 5rem;
}

#nav-bar li {
  margin: 2rem;
}

.links {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 1rem;
  color: black;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 0 0 rgba(19, 19, 19, 0.15);
  border-radius: 10px;
  transition: 0s;
}

.links:hover {
    color: white;
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(0,25,36,1) 0%, rgba(54,123,156,1) 0%, rgba(198,153,192,1) 70%);
  transition:.5s;
}


.links:after {
  transform: translateY(4px);
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  #image-list {
    margin: 3rem;
  }

  h1 {
    margin: 5rem 3rem 10rem 3rem;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  #image-list {
    margin: 3rem;
  }
}


let animation = document.querySelector('.ease');
let img1 = document.querySelector('li:nth-child(1)');
let img2 = document.querySelector('li:nth-child(2)');
let song1 = document.querySelector('#song1');
let song2 = document.querySelector('#song2');

//play pause 
img1.addEventListener('click', function() {
    if(song1.paused) {
        song1.play();
        //this.classList.toggle('ease');
    } else {
        song1.pause();
        //this.classList.toggle('ease');
    }
});

img2.addEventListener('click', function() {
    if(song2.paused) {
        song2.play();
        //this.classList.toggle('ease');
    } else {
        song2.pause();
        //this.classList.toggle('ease');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

When you start playing one song just stop another.

```
img1.addEventListener('click', function() {
    if(song1.paused) {
        song2.pause(); // <--- this piece
        song1.play();
    } else {
        song1.pause();
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi sorry I'm so late to this. I tried your method and it says "song2.pause is not a function"

Comment: also, at some point, I would like to have around 5 sounds. At this point, should I make a loop? I've tried to make an array of sounds then loop them every time I click, but it's not working.